# workaround for QTBUG-26538

Tags: qt, sockets, udp, qt5, qiodevice

I am developing an application that has to run on ubuntu 14.04, that bundles qt 5.2.1.
I use QUdpSocket as QIODevice, so I first bind to a port where my server accept datagrams, then I call connectToHost().
Unfortunately I have to face with [[QTBUG-26538] QUdpSocket: connectToHost() resets local port number specified by bind()](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26538)
There is some workoaround?

Comment: What if "87.250.251.3:20000"?

Comment: @AlexanderVX I have to bind a predefined local port. What you suggest is done by connectToHost()

Comment: I meant string parameter.